# Costmap's free-space depending on gmapping?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, costmap, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I realized that /costmap topic only publishes OBSTACLE, INFLATED and UNKNOWN space. All the rest is assumed to be FREE space.
Now I need to get all available freespace blocks within my local costmap. As soon as the robot moves, the costmap steadily changes with direct impact on obstacle and inflated space.
Now I wonder if this is different to free space. As I discovered, SLAM gmapping requires some time to create the map. During this time the amount of free space blocks do not change, which results in the fact that free space is not available in the instantiated costmap until the underlying map is created.

Which approach can be used to mitigate this behaviour?

```
- Faster updates of the SLAM map
- Somehow update freespace blocks, whenever the costmap changes
```

I really appreciate every hint. Thanks

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111281/costmap%27s-free-space-depending-on-gmapping?/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally increasing the map update rate solved the problem.
Now freespace is updated on every map update cycle and therefore immediately available!

Here is my gmapping.launch file:

```
  <param name="xmin" value="-5.0"/>
  <param name="ymin" value="-5.0"/>
  <param name="xmax" value="5.0"/>
  <param name="ymax" value="5.0"/>
  <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
  <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
</node>
```

Hope this helps you,

BR Daniel

---

Originally posted by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) with karma: 205 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1